# How to remove last 3 characters from a list of String in java?

Tags: java, string

I have a list which contains some String in this format  23:45:50 ,12:32:70 etc. I want to cut this last two digits after `:`.

I am using `substring()` but it is not working properly,I am posting my code:

```
public class SplitString {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
    aList.add("4:78:34");
    aList.add("5:8:34");
    aList.add("8:18:90");
    aList.add("2:8:40");


    for(int i=0;i<aList.size();i++){

        String str = aList.get(i).substring(0, aList.get(i).length()-3);
        aList.add(str);

    }
    System.out.println(aList);
}

}
```

But giving the result

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
at com.test.SplitString.main(SplitString.java:19)
```

I  want the output as 23:45,12:32

Comment: Try printing out `i` at each loop. I think you'll be surprised by how many times it runs ;). I expect it's about. . . 13 times until it errors.

Comment: why don't you do subString here ??  aList.add("4:78:34");

Comment: @ScottSelby i can not do substring there because i will get the list dynamically after getting i  have to do these modificfation

Comment: You are adding new elements to your list instead of replacing the existing ones.

Comment: Learn http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)

Comment: @ScottSelby can you provide a solution??

Comment: debug. run step by step and watch the content of each variables and expression at each step.

Comment: problem in here: aList.add(str);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a new list to storage the sub string. Do you know when your for-cycle break? I debugged it and get that it will break when your alist.size()=0. The exception causes when the aList.get(i).length()<3. So you just do like this:

```
`
        List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
        aList.add("4:78:34");
        aList.add("5:8:34");
        aList.add("8:18:90");
        aList.add("2:8:40");
        List<String> subList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++)
        {

            String str = aList.get(i).substring(0, aList.get(i).length() - 3);
            subList.add(str);

        }
        System.out.println(subList);`
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked up a recursive function for you to call to get the string after the right most colon. So if you can find another colon, it keeps looking further. If it can't it returns what's left.

```
public static String getRight(String str) {
    if (str.indexOf(':') > 0) {
        str = getRight(str.substring(str.indexOf(':')+1));
    }

    return str;
}
```

As PM 77-1 said, you are adding more items to your list so it can't ever get to the end of the list. You need to store the original count if you are to ever get out of your for loop. Here is your fully modified code tested and working:

```
public class SplitString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
        aList.add("4:78:34");
        aList.add("5:8:34");
        aList.add("8:18:90");
        aList.add("2:8:40");

        int original_size = aList.size();
        for(int i=0;i<original_size;i++){
            String str = aList.get(i);
            aList.add(getRight(str));
        }
        System.out.println(aList);
    }

    public static String getRight(String str) {
        if (str.indexOf(':') > 0) {
            str = getRight(str.substring(str.indexOf(':')+1));
        }

        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use str.lastIndexOf(':')? Also, Subho wanted to cut the last 3 characters, not to extract them.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8:

```
aList = aList.stream().map(w -> w.substring(0, w.length()-3)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```